# enum return undefined when a key has an accent character

Tags: javascript, enums

I am trying to find a string from enum when I find Mär from enum it returns undefined it should return Mar value.

EnumClass

```
{'Jan' : 'Jan' , 'Feb' : 'Feb', 'Mär' : 'Mar'}

console.log(enumClass.monthLangDE[localeMonth]) //undefined
```

also when I do `console.log(localeMonth)` it displays Mär

Comment: what browser? works fine in chrome console.

Comment: `console.log(escape(localeMonth), escape('Mär'));` My guess is there is something different

Comment: You should look into [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) as there is no need to handle different locales on your own.

Comment: @epascarello, yes they are different M%E4r M%uFFFDr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something is wrong with the encoding when

```
console.log(escape(localeMonth), escape('Mär')); //produces "M%E4r M%uFFFDr"
```

So make sure that the JavaScript code file is saved as UTF-8 and that the page is running as UTF-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

If that does not fix anything, than you can do:

```
{'Jan' : 'Jan' , 'Feb' : 'Feb', 'M\u00E4r' /*'Mär'*/ : 'Mar'}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :). Can you please explain a little on M\u00E4r?

Comment: It is just the encoding: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/E4/index.htm